# probability distribution of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, dirac-delta-distributions, randomness

If we have dependent random variables, then what how is the distribution the pdf look like? Can it be a normal distribution?
For example, additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) has a normal distribution, since the samples are not dependent. But if we have a signal whose samples are correlated, then they will not necessarily follow a normal distribution.
So, how the distribution of a dependent random variable looks like?

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be describing is a signal for which the present amplitude correlates with previous amplitudes.  Any signal exhibiting this behavior is said to exhibit stochastic behavior, and is a Markov process.

To answer your question directly, the distribution of the signal would depend entirely on what kind of correlation-relationship the present amplitude has with previous amplitudes.  There's no one specific distribution that the signal would have.

Answer (score 0):

When a stationary normal noise process $X(t)$ is passed through a filter whose impulse response is $h(t)$ then we can calculate the spectrum $S_y$ of the output process $Y(t)$ from the spectrum $S_x$ of the input process using $$S_y(u) = |H(u)|^2 S_x(u)$$
where $H(u)=\int h(t) e^{-i2\pi ut}dt$ and $S_x(u)=lim_{B \to \infty} \frac{2}{B}|\int_{-B}^{B} dt X(t)e^{-i2\pi ut}|^2$. Since the sum of arbitrary number of of jointly normal rv-s is also normal, hence the convolution integral representing the output process is stationary normal as well if the input process is. Therefore the auto-correlation function $K_y(\tau)=\textbf{E}[{Y(t)Y(t-\tau)]}$ of $Y$ that is the inverse Fourier transform of its spectrum will fully characterize the process:
$$K_y(\tau)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}du S_y(u)e^{i2\pi u\tau}$$